# Look through the portal of every day

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Look through the portal of every day,
>   It shows you the world in a different way.
>   Darkened or dyed, or simply crystal clear,
>   Just keep your fingers off or you might leave a smear.
>   Two arms does it have, to not get lost,
>   And a bridge to connect, but not to be crossed.

What is it?

*Part of the [everyday object series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=body%3A%22everyday+object+series%22+is%3Aquestion)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is

> A pair of glasses

Look through the portal of every day,

> The lenses in the glasses form a visual portal to the surrounding world.

It shows you the world in a different way.

> For those who need glasses, their vision is improved.

Darkened or dyed, or simply crystal clear,

> You can have sunglasses or just the regular kind without a tint.

Just keep your fingers off or you might leave a smear.

> Fingers can leave smears on the lenses.

Two arms does it have, to not get lost,

> To hook over the ears

And a bridge to connect, but not to be crossed.

> The bridge goes over the nose

Comment: Uh, beat me to it, nice

Comment: Damn, that was so fast that I cannot accept the answer yet, but you're correct

Answer (score 3):

Look through the portal of every day,

> Glasses

It shows you the world in a different way.

> You see better with glasses

Darkened or dyed, or simply crystal clear,

> Sunglasses or regular ones

Just keep your fingers off or you might leave a smear.

> You don't want to touch the sunglasses because you won't see clear

Two arms does it have, to not get lost,

> 2 arms on either side

And a bridge to connect, but not to be crossed.

> there is a bridge between the two eye pieces